# Openshift exporting environment variable through action hooks

Tags: openshift

Im trying to set some environment variable through action hooks, but it fails to add these varibles, here is my start script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# The logic to start up your application should be put in this
# script. The application will work only if it binds to
# $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:8080
nohup $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/testrubyserver.rb $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP $OPENSHIFT_REP                                                                                                                                                             O_DIR/diy |& /usr/bin/logshifter -tag diy &

touch ~/app-root/data/test1

export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/gradle
export GRADLE_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/gradle-1.6
export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

touch ~/app-root/data/test2
```

Now im doing those 2 "touch" to make sure the script is running, and it is, but the variables are never set.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/gradle
```